# use xslt to create tag in in parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Suppose I have an XML document something like this (note that for my purposes, the order the tags appear in the final document doesn't matter, in case that makes a difference; we're just using XML as a fancy key/value pair contraption)

```
<MyRoot>
 various tags here I don't care about at the moment
 <child><GoldenTag>1234</GoldenTag></child>
</MyRoot>
```

Note that the value of GoldenTag is not always 1234; this was just for illustration.  Now, I want to create a SilverTag that is a (direct) child of MyRoot, whose value is the same as GoldenTag, assuming that GoldenTag exists and various other conditions are met.

I see no good way to do this, because if I use `template mach='GoldenTag'` then the contents of the template ends up inside the `child` tag which is not where I want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any match on `MyRoot` can of course also include conditions on other elements e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="MyRoot[child/GoldenTag and your-other-conditions]">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <SilverTag><xsl:value-of select="child/GoldenTag"/></SilverTag>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Cool!  can I leave out the `copy` tag?

Comment: I would "translate" your description "I want to create a SilverTag that is a (direct) child of MyRoot" into the above code, together with the identity transformation set up. The `xsl:copy` in the sample serves to recreate the `MyRoot` in the output, if you don't want that, you of course don't need to use it, if you want it but want to literally spell out your result element name, you can of course also write `<MyRoot><xsl:apply-templates/><SilverTag><xsl:value-of select="child/GoldenTag"/></SilverTag></MyRoot>`.

Comment: So you're saying the `copy` is to make up for the fact that there was no identity transform?

Comment: I have focused on showing the code for that particular part you said you struggled with, to find a match pattern that has your conditions and allows creating a `SilverTag` as a child of `MyRoot`. The `apply-templates` I have used kind of assumes having the identity transformation template set up for the rest, although in a limited context you could of course use `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` instead. Of course you can't insert a new node with the identity transformation alone, so I am not sure what your last comment refers to.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used XSLT before.  Just re-read my comment and it indeed makes very little sense.  One more question: can this "trick" be used more than once?  That is, imagine in addition to copying child/GoldenTag into SilverTag, can I also copy kid/BronzeTag into Sparkle?  My intuition tells me that this is weird because we're matching the root too many times and it's not obvious (to me) how the XSLT processor can reconcile all the different "versions".

Comment: @MarkVY You forgot to accept Martin's answer -- this is definitely not fair since he did all the work for you and spent considerable time trying to reply to your comments and educate you. Please!

Comment: it's not the answer I ended up using (I used mine) but since I'd have never figured out mine without him, you're right

Answer (score 0):

Based on Martin's answer, I think (hope?) something like this should work:

```
<xsl:template match="child[GoldenTag and other-tests]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <SilverTag>
        <xsl:value-of select="GoldenTag"/>
    </SilverTag>
</xsl:template>
```